# a question of indefinite article "an"

Tags: grammar, indefinite-article, ielts

There is a passage on the website below
https://ieltsonlinetests.com/ielts-mock-test-2023-january-reading-practice-test-3?mode=practice_test&parts=1&duration=60
Here is a question about the passage I don't understand:

> He did not make **an effort** after becoming a high-ranking official in
> the army.

question: Is this statement correct concerning Nash’s story?

for the convenience, I pasted the relative context here

> In March 1917, he was sent to the Western Front Nash, who took part in
> the offensive at Ypres, had reached the rank of lieutenant in the
> Hampshire Regiment by 1916. Whenever possible, Nash made sketches of
> life in the trenches. In May 1917 he was invalided home after a
> non-military accident. While recuperating in London, Nash worked from
> his sketches to produce a series of war paintings.

Do you know what "an effort" means in the question given the information?
I thought the effort could mean trying hard to paint.
it also can mean making an effort to get a higher position in the army.
In other words, the answer to the question is not clear.
what do you think?

Comment: I can't read the passage without logging in, but apparently Paul Nash was only a second lieutenant before he was appointed as a war artist. **An effort after becoming** doesn't mean **an effort to become**.

Comment: The quoted text refers to Nash being a lieutenant, which is the lowest rank of officer.  It doesn't related to him becoming a high ranking official.  Note that one doesn't talk about "Officials" in the army but "Officers".  Paul Nash was never a high ranking officer.